# Determine the distribution of a random variable

Tags: probability, distributions

I want to solve the following

A salesman has two different stores where he sells computers. The
probability that he sells, in one day, a computer in the first store is $0.4$ and
independently, the probability that he sells, in one day, a computer in the
second store is $0.7$. Additionally, suppose that it is equally probable that he
sells a computer of type $1$ or type $2$. A type $1$ computer costs $1800$ while
the type $2$ computer, with the same specifications, costs $1000$. Let $X$ be the
amount, in dollars, that the salesman sells in one day. Find the distribution
of the random variable $X$.

I think it is convenient to analyze this according to different situations:

1. If the gain is zero, then no computers will have been sold anywhere so:

$$P(X=0)=(1-0.4)(1-0.7)=0.18$$

2.If the profit is 1000, then you will have sold a $2$ type computer in first or second place. Apparently the value here is

$$P(X=1000)=0.27$$

But it is not entirely clear to me how this value arises, and how can the remaining values be deducted to determine the distribution?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is the probability that he sells exactly one computer?  Then, since there's a 50-50 chance it's a type 2 computer, the probability that he sells exactly one computer and it's a type 2 computer is... (fill in the blanks.)